# facebook authentication -is this use of the token correct?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

After authenticating the user, I save the authorization token insidea database. Than I save his Id inside a cookie. Each time he accesses a page I check to see if the cookie is there. If it s not there, I try to get another authorization cookie and replace the old in the database, and create that cookie.

I have a deep feeling I am wrong:0 Can you tell me how should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not deal directly with cookies but use a SDK that do it for you. For C#, you can use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). Check out the [API Quickstart guide](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=QuickStart%20using%20the%20API&referringTitle=Documentation) if you want to have a good overview.

You should store the token in you database **only** if you ask the `offline_access` permission when you get the access token because token expires after a few hours.

If you do ask for the `offline_access` permission when you get the token, then you can store it in your database and make API calls with that token anytime you want (without having to check the user session or cookie).

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Can you explain me breifly how this works?Does FacebookWebClient store the token in some static field? If for instance I want to get the user's name on index.aspx, and that I want to get the name also when the user navigates to about.aspx, what code should be on each page? Could you leae edit your answer to explain this. It would help me hugely

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET but what the SDK may do is to store the access token in the session so you can keep making API calls as long as your session is active and the user si still connected. It seems that, when the user is logged in, you just have to make `var client = new FacebookWebClient();` and then make API calls (like `client.Get("me")`).

Comment: @Ryan The access token is probably stores in the user cookies as well. Otherwise, he would have have to re-authenticate each time his session expire in your server.